# Why only String type return value are checked at run time in java generic

Tags: java, generics

I am reading  Thinking in java , Generics. In one example(at paragraph "The action at the boundaries")

```
public class GenericHolder<T> {
    private T obj;
    public void set(T obj) { this.obj = obj; }
    public T get() { return obj; }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericHolder<String> holder =
        new GenericHolder<String>();
        holder.set("Item");
        String s = holder.get();
    }
} ///:~


public void set(java.lang.Object);
    0: aload_0
    1: aload_1
    2: putfield #2; //Field obj:Object;
    5: return
public java.lang.Object get();
    0: aload_0
    1: getfield #2; //Field obj:Object;
    4: areturn
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    470 Thinking in Java Bruce Eckel
    0: new #3; //class GenericHolder
    3: dup
    4: invokespecial #4; //Method "<init>":()V
    7: astore_1
    8: aload_1
    9: ldc #5; //String Item
    11: invokevirtual #6; //Method set:(Object;)V
    14: aload_1
    15: invokevirtual #7; //Method get:()Object;
    18: checkcast #8; //class java/lang/String
    21: astore_2
    22: return
```

According to the disassembled code line 18, the compiler adds the checkcast code. I want to know if it is always to such a checkcast for generic. I replaced the String to Integer and tried again, but I didn't find the checkcast code at last. So does the Object type.

Could someone explain that? Is `String` in Java is a special Object?

Comment: For `Object` it would need no cast, since everything can be cast to Object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***I replace the String to Integer and tried again, but I didn't find the checkcast code at last.***

For me it produces a `checkcast` also for `Integer`:

```
  0: new    #3; //class GenericHolder
  3: dup
  4: invokespecial  #4; //Method GenericHolder."<init>":()V
  7: astore_1
  8: aload_1
  9: iconst_5
 10: invokestatic   #5; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)
 13: invokevirtual  #6; //Method GenericHolder.set:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
 16: aload_1
 17: invokevirtual  #7; //Method GenericHolder.get:()Ljava/lang/Object;
 20: checkcast  #8; //class java/lang/Integer
 23: astore_2
 24: return
```

As you can see, the `get` method has the signature `Ljava/lang/Object;` i.e., the `checkcast` is to make sure that the `Object` returned is indeed an `Integer`.

---

**Edit:** In the code you posted as a comment:

```
0: getstatic #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
3: new #3; //class b/TestG
6: dup
7: new #4; //class java/lang/Integer
10: dup
11: iconst_2
12: invokespecial #5; //Method java/lang/Integer."<init>":(I)V
15: invokespecial #6; //Method b/TestG."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
18: invokevirtual #7; //Method b/TestG.getT:()Ljava/lang/Object;
21: invokevirtual #8; //Method java/io/PrintStream.print:(Ljava/lang/Objec t;)V 
24: return
```

you pass on the returned value to `PrintStream.print` which accepts an `Object`. Thus, there is no need to cast the returned value. (`checkcast java.lang.Object` would always go through!)

Comment: 7:   new     #4; //class java/lang/Integer
   10:  dup
   11:  iconst_2
   12:  invokespecial   #5; //Method java/lang/Integer."<init>":(I)V
   15:  invokespecial   #6; //Method b/TestG."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   18:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method b/TestG.getT:()Ljava/lang/Object;
   21:  invokevirtual   #8; //Method java/io/PrintStream.print:(Ljava/lang/Objec
t;)V
   24:  return    I use the javap -c filename and there is no such a code?

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much.. I am new to java, the generic seems so confused to me.

Comment: Hehe... Looking at the generated bytecode won't get you far with generics, as the type-parameters are erased at compile time (and replaced by `Object`). Read up on *type erasure* for further details.